# CodeIgniter, refreshing view for all clients

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, refresh

There is my problem.
My project is using CodeIgniter.

I'm working on a game, during this phase, the player must choose a music.
He got a **form** to send the URL. Other player have to **wait him**, and I want to **refresh view for everyone** when the player has sent the music.

I did first a JS function which refresh every second the page, the problem is if the player write something in the form it will refresh for him too.

Is it possible to do something like that with CodeIgniter ?

```
<script>
setInterval("auto_refresh_test_refresh()",1000);
function auto_refresh_test_refresh(){ 
        $( "#test_refresh" ).load(window.location.href + " #test_refresh" );
}
</script>
```

This is my JS function with the problem.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Is it possible to do something like what? What are you trying to accomplish because right now it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Alex, I'm trying to refresh my view for every clients when the player has choosen his music...

Comment: ok so then what does this mean? "the problem is if the player write something in the form it will refresh for him too."

Comment: Ok, if there is 5 client, 2 will be "player", and 3 others will be "judge". The 3 "judge" just have a message on their screen "Players are choosing music" during this time "players" have to choose their music with a form, and I want to refresh the page of the 5 clients when the players send their form, for the moment, when player send his form, it's refreshing his page but nothing for "judge".

Comment: ok but how do you want to handle things when 1 player hasn't selected the music but the other has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try Websockets, they are a open persistent connection with the server, and allow to stream files (or messages) to the clients.